# Transform text using regex in camel.xml

Tags: regex, apache-camel, fuseesb

How can I delete some text from this code
 http://pastebin.com/09N1GzdR and leave only text between first and last Structure tags? I've tried to use replaceAll with regex like :

```
<transform>
<simple>${body.replaceAll("&lt;Structure&gt;([^]*)&lt;\/Structure&gt;", "")}</simple>
</transform>
```

but nothing works. Exception is

```
Failed to invoke method: .replaceAll("<Structure>([^]*)<\/Structure>", "") on null due     to: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: replaceAll("<Structure>([^]*)<\/Structure>", "") on null due to: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 16
"<Structure>([^]*
                ^
```

I think the problem is in open and close parenthesises.  But escaping like `\(` or `&#40;` doesn't help

Comment: @AvinashRaj: In JavaScript, it is legal (`[^]` is equivalent to "`.` including newlines", which is useful because JavaScript doesn't have a `/s` modifier. The `[\s\S]` idiom is more common, though, probably because it's more portable).

Comment: You want to leave only text without tags? To calculate the hash code from the values on it? If so, would a simple java code be sufficient?

Comment: I'd like to leave text with Structure-tags and do this only in xml

Comment: Check this (http://regex101.com/r/kZ9zW6/2) out. If it helps you let me know and I'll paste it as an answer :)

Comment: Are you loading this `xml` from file or it's a part of some... (sub)element... something :) And you are processing this with JavaScript, right? (I see the `replaceAll` method but just to make it sure :)

Comment: I'm getting it from body in camel-context and process it with spring. Here is some example http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/String-replacement-via-Spring-td5719498.html